# Single Linkage Clustering in R - Merging step

Tags: r, cluster-computing, bioinformatics, hierarchical-clustering

So i want to implement a Single Linkage Clustering Algorithm and i know there are a lot of packages with template functions to do single linkage clustering like hclust, but i want to implement this algorithm by myself using a for loop.

The difficult part is, i honestly don't know how to update the matrix after i have found a cluster pair. Let's say the minimum in the matrix is 1 between two points "A" and "B" and we have a 5x5 matrix. Now, would i have to make a new column and remove these both columns, since i now have a new cluster point V?

How does the new distance matrix look like implemented though? I need to compute new distances to cluster V. I have a problem understanding this. Would love to see an example maybe. Maybe you guys can help.

My Matrix:

A B C D E

0 1 2 5 4

1 0 6 2 2

2 6 0 8 2

5 2 8 0 4

4 2 2 4 0

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a tabulated matrix like you have here). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function or by writing the matrix within R and pasting it in your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

Eucledian Distance in 1D.

Single Linkage takes the minimum of euclidian among all pairs of points in two cluster.

```
dist(Va, C) = 2
dist(vb, C) = 6
dist(V,C) = min(2,6) =2

dist(Va, D) = 5
dist(vb, D) = 2
dist(V,C) = min(2,5) =2

dist(Va, E) = 4
dist(vb, E) = 2
dist(V,C) = min(2,4) =2
```

The new distance matrix looks like:

```
V C D E

0 2 2 2 

2 0 8 2

2 8 0 4

2 2 4 0
```

Now you are free to cluster V with either C, D, E because all three clusters are at same distance.